# WCF WebService - Is there a way to determine that client received response?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, ws-reliablemessaging

Lets say I have a WCF service that a client can use to receive message from some server side message queue. As an example, lets say there is a server-side queue of email in a data table:

```
ID | MESSAGE_TEXT | SENT
------------------------
1  | Hi!          | N
2  | A 2nd Msg    | N
```

Lets define our service as:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<string> GetMessages()
{
    var messages = LoadMessagesFromDb();
    var messageText = (from m in messages select m.MessageText).ToArray();
    return messageText;
}
```

Lets assume that LoadMessagesFromDb() just grabs all the messages where SENT = 'N'. So we load those, and then extract all the text strings and return them.

Now my issue here is that I really need to mark those messages as "sent = 'Y'" in my data table.  I could do something like:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<string> GetMessages()
{
    var messages = LoadMessagesFromDb();
    var messageText = (from m in messages select m.MessageText).ToArray();

    // mark sent
    foreach(var msg in messages)
        MarkSentInDb(msg.ID);

    return messageText;
}
```

However, what happens if there is an error in returning the data to the client? Possibly a connectivity issue, or a WCF serialization issue?  What I'd really like to do is somehow know that the client received the message successfully.  The only thing I can think of right now is make a 2nd method that the client can call to indicate that the items were received successfully:

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [DataMemeber]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

then have a 2nd method on the service:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Message> GetMessages();

[OperationContract]
public void ConfirmMessagesReceived(List<long> messageIds);
```

So the client would have to send all the IDs back to me.  Is there a better way to do this?  If I were doing this in ASP.NET instead of WCF, I could have the method open the response stream and write back the data, and have that in a try/catch, but I don't seem to have the same flexibility in WCF, without making a bunch of custom message writers and extensions...  Anyone have a better idea how to tell if there is an error during transmit back to the client? Does ws-reliablemessaging give me anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ReliableSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx) (available with the WsHttpBinding) would transparently ensure that your messages are received by the client in the case of transport-level errors. Errors in the serialization layer on the client side would have to be handled there.

If you needed more acknowledgment from the client, you could implement a duplex service (using the [WsDualHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx)) contract to easily communicate back to the server from the client.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I am using wsHttpBinding already, so I think the Reliable Sessions will work for me.  I just need to see how non-wcf clients like it.  Some of our clients use Java, and I think one is on VB5 still.